# Slow first visit on precompiled view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, iis, precompile

I've precompiled my application:
[precompilation settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mksx0.png), also set compilation configs to

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.6.2"
             batch="false"
             debug="false"
             optimizeCompilations="true">
</compilation>
```

but on every first visit to the page it still takes long time (not only the first request to the application, which could be explained by application initialization, but first request to each view, even after app has been initialized).

I've used profilers to check whether it's our code or not, but it executes fast. There's around 20 seconds delay (sometimes even up to 60 seconds) on the first page visit. Profiler shows this (response for first page visit is being returned with delay), even though view is precompiled (note the 20 seconds delay after last SQL query and response):
[profiler result on first request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JWA3.png).

Response for each next page request is being returned immediately:
[profiler result on second request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49eEx.png).

I've checked ORM initialization, tried to minify js/css, gzip them and check every other known option, but to no avail. Every view / page on first request returns slow, even though application and app pool are warmed up.

I then enabled tracing in IIS and found the following:
[delay after HANDLER_CHANGED event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8IOc.png)

The delay is happening after handler is changed. Now... the weird, I guess thing, it's being changed from OldHandlerName which is null. Can that be the cause? Or maybe something with the event which occurs after delay (HttpCacheModule)? I've found several other findings like this, connected to slow initial page requests here, but none of them were properly answered. One of those answers can be found [here](https://forums.iis.net/t/1235023.aspx?Pages%20are%20Loading%20Slowly%20FREB%20shows%20Delay%20between%20HANDLER_CHANGED%20and%20NOTIFY_MODULE_START%20), but changing outputCache did not help. My outputCache settings:

```
<caching>
    <outputCacheSettings>
         <!--outputCacheSettings - Controls how controller actions cache content in one central location.
                           You can also modify the web configuration file without recompiling your application.--> 
        <outputCacheProfiles>
             <!--Cache the 400 Bad Request route for a day.--> 
            <add name="BadRequest" duration="86400" location="Server" varyByParam="none" />
             <!--Cache the 403 Forbidden route for a day.--> 
            <add name="Forbidden" duration="86400" location="Server" varyByParam="none" />
             <!--Cache the 405 Method Not Allowed route for a day.--> 
            <add name="MethodNotAllowed" duration="86400" location="Server" varyByParam="none" />
             <!--Cache the 404 Not Found route for a day.--> 
            <add name="NotFound" duration="86400" location="Server" varyByParam="none" />
             <!--Cache the 401 Unauthorized route for a day.--> 
            <add name="Unauthorized" duration="86400" location="Server" varyByParam="none" />
             <!--Cache the 500 Internal Server Error route for a day.--> 
            <add name="InternalServerError" duration="86400" location="Server" varyByParam="none" />
        </outputCacheProfiles>
    </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

I'm hitting the wall here... any ideas?

:EDIT: 
AFter further analysis, it turns out that even after precompilation is ran, the

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

is not filled with dlls on deployment. When I run

```
aspnet_compiler -v /virtual_path
```

it does in fact precompile all pages to that Temporary folder, but then when I access page for the first time, then a second shallow copy of that .dll is created, which results in delay. After that file is created by IIS and not precompilation tools, view works okay.

So... it looks like IIS has no idea, that those dlls are already precompiled and ready for action. Do you know how to make it known for it? Can we even disable Temporary ASP.NET Files altogether and force it to use only bin folders of our applications?

:EDIT2: I see that there is an option in IIS Pages and Controls, called Compilation Mode and it's "Always" by default (which means that it forces compilation anyway), but as mentioned in msdn, these settings apply to ASP.NET Webforms only. There must be somewhere similar setting for MVC. Help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Precompiling doesn't do everything you think of. It does compile into a dll, but that dll then needs to be converted from IL into machine code. This happens when you spin up the application in IIS. IF you are on WIndows Server 2012 or above, there are features that you can set in the app pool to help it stay hot after it's been loaded using the Always Running start mode.

You can find this setting by opening the IIS manager | Application Pools | select the appropriate App Pool | Advanced Settings and set the Start Mode to Always Running.

The initial hit should still take some compilation time, but after that the application should stay loaded and only be torn down in the event the application pool is forced to recycle.

Comment: App pool is already set to always running, application preLoad has been enabled and appInitialization is also enabled. This could be a solution in case of only a first request to application at all being slow, but we're talking about each first request per page, even after application has been properly initialized. So we have Page1, Page2, Page3. We hit Page1 (say we don't have auto-start of app-pool, so application is being initialized and then view is rendered), but then when we hit Page2 and Page3, then delay also occurs on first hits to them.

Comment: Is this defined as a web application project or as a website project?

Comment: It's ASP.NET MVC web application, hosted under Default Web Site of IIS.

Comment: That is unusual. Are there C# Razor functions inline in the views?

Comment: Nope, just DevExpress controls are used in views, no C# Razor functions.

Comment: Yeah, that part is bizarre. Just for giggles, does this happen on a view that contains no third-party components? Additionally, can identify some commonality, such as perhaps a shared view that is in all the affected pages? Could there be something that is attempting to load Session or some other persistent logic that is spinning up on each page, like maybe a page/action  level caching mechanism?

Comment: I've added edit to original question. Turns out that IIS does not care about precompiled .dlls and forces compilation of its own to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files . Looks like some setting needs to be changed, so it wouldn't always compile on its own. Dunno where yet.